# New to wxwidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

I have currently the following environment in Windows: CodeBlocks with wxWidgets and wxSmith as my GUI builder

I have created a sample wxWidgets project and would like to have access to the gtk+ components via wxWidgets. However the components created via wxSmith seems to point to only the msw components. How can I change this configuration as I would like my default look and feel as gtk.

I have tried replacing the compiler settings: `__WXMSW__` with `__WXGTK20__` and have encountered couple of compilation error messages:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===
error: 'GtkWidget' has not been declared|
error: 'GtkWidget' has not been declared|
error: 'class wxWindow' has no member named 'm_scrollBar'|
error: 'ScrollDir_Horz' is not a member of 'wxWindow'|
error: 'class wxWindow' has no member named 'm_scrollBar'|
error: 'ScrollDir_Vert' is not a member of 'wxWindow'|
```

I believe I'm missing out something, some configuration somewhere but I just can't figure it out as I'm completely new to CodeBlocks and wxWidgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just replace the symbols in the compiler options. You need to rebuild the library itself to use GTK instead of the native MSW toolkit. This can, actually, be done, see https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/docs/msw/gtk.txt, but this is an experimental platform and I don't advise you to use it if you're new to wxWidgets.

If you *really* need GTK under Windows (why?), the simplest is probably to build it under Cygwin and use X11 backend.